# Using plink commands from Rstudio with the AWS EC2 has disabled the instance DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, rstudio, genetics

I was trying to process GWAS data using plink1.9 with a rental AWS ubuntu server. I executed the plink commands from the terminal window in the Rstudio server.
It turned out that if I execute a plink command that overloads the server, my Rstudio server will become inaccessible and this problem does not revolve.
for example my Rstudio-server from port 8787 has become unavailable.
http://ec2-54-64-41-xxx.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8787/

I accidentally did it twice. First time I did something like `cat xxx.vcf` (how stupid of me) and the server simply went frozen and the Rstudio server crashed.
Since I could still access the server with putty and winscp and so on I managed to get my files to a new instance. Then I tried to use plink to do some QC, something like
`./plink --bfile xxx--mind 1 --geno 0.01 --maf 0.05 --make-bed --out yyy`
It had again overloaded the server and the same Rstudio server trouble occurred again.

Now both instances are still accessible from putty, I logged on to check the running processes and it seemed to be fine. There were no active heavy jobs and no zombie processes either.

The CPU monitoring looks fine too.

With the only problem that the Rstudio-server link is not working.

Does anyone have similar experiences? Your advice is very much appreciated.

mindy